# Unable to access Internet with Shiny App in Docker

Tags: docker, shiny, proxy

My computer is behind a proxy

I built a docker image with a Shiny App and with this lines in the dockerfile :

```
ENV http_proxy=myproxy.fr:5555
ENV https_proxy=myproxy.fr:5555
```

When I run the docker, my Shiny App starts well but it stops 2mn later because it can't access to the internet. In the log file there is this error :

> ```
> Warning in file(file, "rt") :
>   unable to connect to 'www.openstreetmap.org' on port 80.
> Warning: Error in file: cannot open the connection
> ```

And the Shiny App works well outside the docker, even behind the proxy

It appears that the ENV variable are only set for the root user.

Any clue to deal with this proxy issue in Docker ?

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the proxy variables in

```
/etc/R/Renviron.site
```

while building the image and it works now ;-)